# The speed of 'this' vs a cached var in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, requestanimationframe

I'm usually not too concerned with micro-optimisations, until it comes to javascript UI performance (particularly on mobile) and keeping everything under the holy 16.666666667ms to get that smooth uninterrupted 60fps.

I'm running a tick function from requestAnimationFrame until a condition is met, and it relies on some values such as this.velocity, this.translateX etc that are set on the current instance.

My Question is, would or should using a cached version of `this` as in `var _this = this;` declared outside the tick rather than referring to `this all over the place be faster?.  To be clear I'm calling this more than a few times.... heres some code :

```
swipeIt.prototype.tick = function() {
    if (Math.abs(this.translateX) < (+this.elWidth*1.2 && this.velocity > 6) ) {


        this.velocity = this.velocity*1.15;
        this.translateX = (this.dir === 'left') ? this.translateX - this.velocity : this.translateX + this.velocity;

        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          _this._update(_this.updateCb);
          _this.tick();
        });

    } else {
       //....
    }
}
```

any other suggestions on optimising this further would be welcome, its the first time im really giving this a solid go.  cheers.

Comment: reference seems to be much faster.

Comment: not according to this http://jsperf.com/this-vs-reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you won't see any improvement from that. If there is any difference at all it will be a tiny performance decrease, because of the extra statement.

You've probably seen something like:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

in jQuery. That makes a lot of sense, because `$(this)` is expensive to evaluate, so code that is littered with `$(this)` can be greatly improved by assigning that to a variable and then using that variable everywhere instead. In your case though, there is nothing costly to evaluate to save on. Accessing `_this` takes just as long as accessing `this`.

Comment: Interestingly, even if you already _have_ a reference, using the reference instead of `this` seems to also incur a tiny performance hit, at least on OS X Chrome (see [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/this-vs-reference)).

Comment: @RyanMuller The magnitude of that slowdown is likely caused by the way Javascript resolves variables. `this` is always in the closest scope, but in that JSPerf `a` isn't in the current function's scope so it has to look at the outer scope to find `a`.

Comment: very interesting, thank you, I liked that jsPerf until you just made me thing about it.....agreed re jQuery.  Though I do have to wonder, a) if you were creating the reference inside the function each time there would be cost, and so its logical to move it outside, where due to scope it does become more expensive, therefore, from an implementation perspective theres joy to be had from going with plain old 'this'.  I get that in the strictest sense of the question though you're correct.

Comment: @pushplaybang I tried adding loops to increase the usage of the reference after it's defined, but I can't seem to get very consistent results: http://jsperf.com/this-vs-reference/2 . At any rate none of those has a significant performance improvement over the others. Nothing in comparison to the improvements you can by caching `$(this)`.

Comment: agreed, but as stated I'm looking to reduce any fat at all from this functions execution time i'm literally a few fractions of a ms away from it consistently running at 60fps, so this question is specifically regarding micro optimisation.

Comment: @pushplaybang Unless you're only running this in one environment, keep in mind that those fractions of a ms, will be a few milliseconds on some other browser running on some other OS with some other CPU, and on someone else's it's already fast enough.